# Separate items in a cart into different checkouts rails

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, cart, checkout

Hi I have setup a shopping cart in my app using this great article https://web-crunch.com/ruby-on-rails-ecommerce-music-shop/

My problem is that, as different items have different sellers, I need the items in the cart to be separated into different checkouts. I managed to do a group by based on the seller:

```
@groups = @cart.line_items.group_by {|line_item| line_item.listing.user_id}.values
```

but I am not sure how to get those separate groups into their own checkouts. Any help would be wonderful!

```
class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :listing
  belongs_to :cart

  def total_price
    listing.price_cents.to_i * quantity.to_i
  end
end

class Checkout < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
end


class Cart < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

  def add_listing(listing)
    current_item = line_items.find_by(listing_id: listing.id)

    if current_item
      current_item.increment(:quantity)
    else
      current_item = line_items.build(listing_id: listing.id)
    end
    current_item
  end

  def total_price
    line_items.to_a.sum { |item| item.total_price }
  end

end
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you post your models with the relationships?

Comment: Now edited with models